# Using spread syntax in Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, spread-syntax

I am trying to use the spread syntax to update the state inside the reducer

The state consists of an object, and the object has an array,

I would like to update all properties in the object, except for the array, which I would like to add the next state elements at the end. For example,

For example, if the state is

```
{
  id: 4,
  amount: 10,
  arr: [
    name: "peter",
    name: "john"
  ]
}
```

and the action

```
{
  id: 7,
  amount: 7,
  arr: [
    name: "sally",
    name: "maria"
  ]
}
```

I would like to get as a result of using the spread syntax

```
{
  id: 7,
  amount: 7,
  arr: [
    name: "peter",
    name: "john",
    name: "sally",
    name: "maria"
  ]
}
```

taking the id and amount of the action, and concatenating the array

Thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Did you try `var newArr = [...oldArr1, ...oldArr2]`?

Comment: @Adelin yes, well, in reality I was getting only the last array as a result, and all else being removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply keep spreading props.

1. spread your current state
2. spread action's payload
3. change properties as needed

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  id: 4,
  amount: 10,
  arr: [
    { name: "peter" },
    { name: "john" },
  ],
}

function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default: return state
    case 'ANY_ACTION': 
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        arr: [
          ...(state.arr || []),
          ...action.payload.arr,
        ]
      }
  }
}

const action = {
  type: 'ANY_ACTION',
  payload: {
    id: 7,
    amount: 7,
    arr: [
      { name: "sally" },
      { name: "maria" },
    ]
  }
}

const state = reducer(undefined, action)
console.log(state)
```

Comment: What if at the beginning arr doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your structure is invalid, the correct structure would look like

```
{
  id: 4,
  amount: 10
  data: [
    {name: "peter"},
    {name: "john"}
  ]
}
```

and then you could use spread operator to update state assuming `action.payload` to be

```
{
  id: 7,
  amount: 7
  data: [
    {name: "sally"},
    {name: "maria"}
  ]
}
```

like

```
case 'WHATEVER_ACTION': 
   return {
        ...state,
        id: action.payload.id,
        amount: action.payload.amount,
        data: [...state.data, ...action.payload.data]
   }
```

Check the documentation of **[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)** to understand its usage more

Comment: I wish I could mark both answers as correct, thank you very much, I will read the documentation indeed.

Comment: I ended up using your answer